# How to keep a log about when screen has been locked/unlocked

Tags: logs, screen-lock

I would like to keep track of the times when I locked/unlocked my computer. I'm running RHEL 6.6 with gnome 2. But maybe there is 'general' solution?

Are there any commands, files or something which keeps track of this?

Or could/should this be done with a script? If so, any pointers what I should be looking into?

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/q/662974 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/13942184